# Custom Lightning Components - Pass record related information from one community page to another

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-web-components

How to pass value from one community page to another page in custom Lightning Components:

variables:  explanation

```
bId  -> recordId
accessIssue ->record write information (true/false) values
```

---

```
 var action = component.get("c.userEditAccessCheck");
       action.setParams({
           bpId: bId
       });
       
       action.setCallback(this, function(actionResult) {
           var state = actionResult.getState();
           console.log('ret--->', actionResult.getReturnValue());
            console.log('state-->',state);
           if (state == "SUCCESS") {
               if(actionResult.getReturnValue()!=null&&actionResult.getReturnValue()!='undefined'){
                window.location.href =  $A.get("$Label.c.PC_CommunityUrl")+'/pc-businessplanrecordeditdetails?Id=' +bId +
                      '&accessIssue='+actionResult.getReturnValue();
               }
                 }
                else if (state === "ERROR") {
               var errors = actionResult.getError();
               console.error(errors);
           }
       });
       $A.enqueueAction(action);
       
   }
```

Apex Class:

```
@AuraEnabled
   public static boolean userEditAccessCheck(string bpId){
       String loggedInUserId=UserInfo.getUserId();
       boolean EditAccess;
       List<UserRecordAccess> userAccessablityCheck=[SELECT RecordId, HasEditAccess FROM UserRecordAccess WHERE UserId=:loggedInUserId AND RecordId=:bpId];
       if(userAccessablityCheck.size()>0)
       {
           if(userAccessablityCheck[0].HasEditAccess==true){
               EditAccess=true;
           }
           else
           {
               EditAccess=false;
           }
       }        
       return EditAccess;
   }
```

I believe exposing the record write permission in url is not safe:

```
window.location.href =  $A.get("$Label.c.PC_CommunityUrl")+'/pc-businessplanrecordeditdetails?Id=' +bId +
                      '&accessIssue='+actionResult.getReturnValue();
```

In this Page: pc-businessplanrecordeditdetails: It opens below Components:

PC_BusinessPlanRecordDetailsEdit

doinit method:

Accessing value from URL

```
var url = new URL(url_string);
var businessplanId = url.searchParams.get("Id");
var acessCheck=url.searchParams.get("accessIssue");
```

Question here:Iam exposing the record Id &accessIssue is url isnot safe.access Issue is nothing but write  access for that record. In url if its false,easily we can change to true.

whats the best way to pass this values from one community page to another.

Comment: Can you format your code properly?

Comment: Do not destroy question content. Please open *new* posts with any clearly distinct issues. Please take a moment to read through [ask] and take the [tour], as well as familiarizing yourself with our editing tools, for your next question.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SFSE, Please use Code formatter when you post the Code in your Question.
in lightning there is [lightning:navigation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:navigation/documentation) to generate URL and [page reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation_page_definitions.htm) to redirect to next page here is example code.

**Sourcecmp**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes">    
<aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{! c.doinit}"/>
<lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>
```

**SourceCmpController**
you have to build and call below custom navigation function from your `doinit` Server call success block.

```
redirectpBusinessPlandetail : function(component,event){
        event.preventDefault();
    var navService = component.find("navService");
        //standard__component
    var pageReference = {
        type: "comm__namedPage",   
        attributes: {
            //componentName: 'imsincidenthelp'
           pageName: "targetcommunitypage"  // your target community page
        },
        state: {
            "Id": "bid" // your variables like bid & accessIssue
        }
    };

    sessionStorage.setItem('localTransfer', JSON.stringify(pageReference.state));    

     // window.open(incurl, '_blank');
    navService.navigate(pageReference);
    },
```

**targetCmp**

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"></aura:handler>
</aura:component>
```

**targetcmpController**

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {

        var localStuff = sessionStorage.getItem('localTransfer');
        console.log("localStuff =>"+localStuff);
        if(localStuff){
            var state = JSON.parse(localStuff);
            console.log(state.Id);

        }

    },
})
```

Let me know if you have any issue with above code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Security-related parameters should absolutely never be visible to the user or under user control.

Security should be implemented in server-side Apex code, which is where you should perform any FLS and CRUD checks that are required and enforce sharing rules to ensure record-level visibility is applied correctly. Your server-side Apex code should always apply these rules *before* returning any data to be rendered by your Lightning client-side code, which is subject to snooping and manipulation by the user.

URL parameters should *never* be used to convey access levels or credentials of any kind. These values should be calculated at the time of access, or persisted in secure server-based storage that is not under the control of the user.